# Trying to compile crosstool-ng-1.20.0

Tags: cross-compiling, toolchain, crosstool-ng

My first try to ./configure crosstool-ng looked like this:

```
 iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local 
--with-libtool=/opt/local/bin/glibtool
--with-libtoolize=/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
--with-objcopy=/opt/local/bin/gobjcopy
--with-objdump=/opt/local/bin/gobjdump
--with-readelf=/opt/local/bin/greadelf
--with-awk=/opt/local/bin/gawk            
--with-sed=/opt/local/bin/gsed 
--with-automake=/opt/local/bin/automake
--with-wget=/opt/local/bin/wget
--with-gcc=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.3
--with-binutils=/opt/local/bin
```

then bla-bla-bla...

```
checking for wget... no
configure: error: missing required tool: wget
```

sure, crosstool-ng do need wget. But it's strange, because I have it!

```
iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ ls -l /opt/local/bin |grep wget
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   499672 Mar  1 00:39 wget
```

ok, made symlink to /usr/bin and that did the trick. I did't remove wget prefix just to see if it warn me somewhere else...  And I was right.

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-wget, --with-gcc, --with-binutils
```

So I removed all unrecognized options...

```
iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local 
--with-libtool=/opt/local/bin/glibtool
--with-libtoolize=/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
--with-objcopy=/opt/local/bin/gobjcopy
--with-objdump=/opt/local/bin/gobjdump
--with-readelf=/opt/local/bin/greadelf
--with-awk=/opt/local/bin/gawk            
--with-sed=/opt/local/bin/gsed 
--with-automake=/opt/local/bin/automake
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /opt/local/bin/gsed
checking whether sed understands -r -i -e... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gperf... gperf
checking for absolute path to gperf... /usr/bin/gperf
checking for bison... bison
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for cut... cut
checking for stat... stat
checking for readlink... readlink
checking for wget... wget
checking for tar... tar
checking for gzip... gzip
checking for bzip2... bzip2
checking for patch... /usr/bin/patch
checking for bash >= 3.1... /bin/bash
checking for GNU awk... (cached) /opt/local/bin/gawk
checking for GNU make >= 3.80... /usr/bin/make
checking whether /usr/bin/make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for make 3.81... yes
checking for GNU libtool >= 1.5.26... (cached) /opt/local/bin/glibtool
checking for GNU libtoolize >= 1.5.26... (cached) /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
checking for GNU automake >= 1.10... (cached) /opt/local/bin/automake
checking for xz... no
checking for lzma... no
checking for cvs... no
checking for svn... svn
checking for inline... inline
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking libintl.h usability... no
checking libintl.h presence... no
checking for libintl.h... no
checking ncurses/ncurses.h usability... no
checking ncurses/ncurses.h presence... no
checking for ncurses/ncurses.h... no
checking ncurses/curses.h usability... no
checking ncurses/curses.h presence... no
checking for ncurses/curses.h... no
checking ncursesw/curses.h usability... no
checking ncursesw/curses.h presence... no
checking for ncursesw/curses.h... no
checking ncurses.h usability... yes
checking ncurses.h presence... yes
checking for ncurses.h... yes
checking for library containing initscr... -lncurses
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

...and voila. It seems all problems gone (?)

```
iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ make
  SED    'ct-ng'
  SED    'scripts/crosstool-NG.sh'
  SED    'scripts/saveSample.sh'
  SED    'scripts/showTuple.sh'
  GEN    'config/configure.in'
  GEN    'paths.mk'
  GEN    'paths.sh'
  DEP    'nconf.gui.dep'
  DEP    'nconf.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/yesno.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/util.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/textbox.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/menubox.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/inputbox.dep'
  DEP    'lxdialog/checklist.dep'
  DEP    'mconf.dep'
  DEP    'conf.dep'
  BISON  'zconf.tab.c'
  GPERF  'zconf.hash.c'
  LEX    'lex.zconf.c'
  DEP    'zconf.tab.dep'
  CC     'zconf.tab.o'
In file included from zconf.tab.c:234:
./zconf.hash.c:177:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'offsetof' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str2),              T_ON,           TF_PARAM},
       ^
./zconf.hash.c:177:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str2),              T_ON,           TF_PARAM},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:178:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str3),              T_OPT_ENV,      TF_OPTION},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:180:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str5),              T_ENDIF,        TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:181:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str6),              T_OPTION,       TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:182:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str7),      T_ENDMENU,      TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:183:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str8),      T_OPTIONAL,     TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:184:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str9),      T_ENDCHOICE,    TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:185:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str10),             T_RANGE,        TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:186:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str11),             T_CHOICE,       TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:187:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str12),     T_DEFAULT,      TF_COMMAND, S_UNKNOWN},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:188:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str13),     T_DEFAULT,      TF_COMMAND, S_BOOLEAN},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:189:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str14),             T_HELP,         TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:191:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str16),             T_CONFIG,       TF_COMMAND},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:192:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str17),     T_DEFAULT,      TF_COMMAND, S_TRISTATE},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:193:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str18),             T_TYPE,         TF_COMMAND, S_HEX},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:194:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str19),     T_OPT_DEFCONFIG_LIST,TF_OPTION},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:196:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str22),             T_IF,           TF_COMMAND|TF_PARAM},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:197:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str23),             T_TYPE,         TF_COMMAND, S_INT},
                ^
./zconf.hash.c:199:17: error: expected expression
      {offsetof(struct kconf_id_strings_t, kconf_id_strings_str27),     T_OPT_MODULES,  TF_OPTION},
                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [zconf.tab.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [build-lib-kconfig] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

And now I just can't get what's wrong. Mb gcc? Just because of wget being recognized only in /usr/bin, I think configure script can't recognize gcc prefix too and it looks for him in /usr/bin, where my default compiler is:

```
 iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ gcc --version
 Configured with: --    prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
 Thread model: posix
```

but not the one from /opt/local/bin

```
iMac:crosstool-ng-1.20.0 rand$ /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.3 --version
gcc-mp-4.3 (MacPorts gcc43 4.3.6_10) 4.3.6
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `offsetof()` requires the `stddef.h` header on OS X. There's a patch here that will make sure it is included:

https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2014-10/msg00021.html

For future reference, the patch is:

```
diff --git a/kconfig/zconf.gperf b/kconfig/zconf.gperf
index c9e690e..d758a2a 100644
--- a/kconfig/zconf.gperf
+++ b/kconfig/zconf.gperf
@@ -7,6 +7,15 @@
 %pic
 %struct-type

+%{
+# ifndef offsetof
+#  include <stddef.h>
+#  ifndef offsetof
+#   define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)(&((st *)0)->m))
+#  endif
+# endif
+%}
+
 struct kconf_id;

 static struct kconf_id *kconf_id_lookup(register const char *str, register unsigned int len);
```

Apply using `patch -p1` :)